# Node Socket.io: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting

Tags: node.js, socket.io, callback

According to Socket.io docs, we can't use a callback while broadcasting but how to catch data sent from the client as a callback in this situation

```
global.SocketService.io.to(member).emit('pushActivity', data, async (returnData) => {
```

This triggers the error `Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting` but is there any workaround or a solution rather than emitting from the client back to the server with the required data?